# AngularJS : How to remove text from a JSON feed?

Tags: json, angularjs, google-calendar-api

I am using ajax (via AngularJS) to grab a Google calendar feed and list the latest events on my homepage. This works great, however, Google seems to append the string **"Event Status: confirmed"** to the events listing at the end of the date. This is what it looks like:

[image]

**I can't seem to hide "Event Status: confirmed" from the feed. Is there a way I can use AngularJS filter to remove that string from my JSON feed?**

The "Event Status: confirmed" text is coming from the `event.summary.$t`property in the JSON feed. This is what the actual property value looks like:

```
"$t": "When: Sun Nov 15, 2015<br />\n\n\n<br />Event Status: confirmed""
```

> Here's my HTML with AngularJS ng-repeat directive looping through the
>   feed:

```
<section id="calendarListing" class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="panel panel-default">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Upcoming Events</h3>
                    </div>
                        <div class="panel-body" ng-controller="CalCtrl">
                        <ul class="list-unstyled" ng-repeat="event in events.feed.entry | reverse | limitTo: 3 ">
                    <li><h4 ng-bind-html="event.title.$t"></h4>
                        <span ng-bind-html="event.summary.$t"></span>
                    </li>    
                </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="panel-footer"><a href="calendar.php"><i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i> View full calendar</a></div>
                </div>
</section><!--/events-->
```

> Here is my script:

```
var calApp = angular.module("calApp", ['ngSanitize']);
var feedUrl = 'https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/ogmda.com_89pas0l9jbhpf053atd83hdj30%40group.calendar.google.com/public/basic?alt=json';

calApp.filter('reverse', function() {
  return function(items) {
    return items.slice().reverse();
  };
});

calApp.controller('CalCtrl', function($http, $scope) {
    $http.get(feedUrl).success(function(data) {
        $scope.events = data;
        console.log(data);
        });
});

angular.element(document).ready(function() {
    angular.bootstrap(document.getElementById("calendarListing"),['calApp']);
});
```

Comment: what does the actual html look like? Should be able to do this with css

Comment: Can you give an actual example of what the JSON looks like for that `$t` property?

Comment: This is what the actual example looks like: "$t": "When: Sun Nov 15, 2015<br />\n\n\n<br />Event Status: confirmed"

Comment: I think you should migrate to using APIv3 or an ICS file as these feeds are going away on Nov 18th: https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/6285065

Comment: Is the JSON going away, too? Looks like only the XML is.

Comment: The private feeds are going away altogether (both XML and JSON versions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd probably just go with a CSS solution. Seems easier that trying to parse out the text. Something like

```
<span class="eventSummary" ng-bind-html="event.summary.$t"></span>
```

and in CSS

```
.eventSummary {
    display: block; /* or inline-block */
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 1.3em; /* or whatever your line-height is */
}
```

---

If you're still keen on actually removing the text, I'd go with a custom filter

```
.filter('singleLine', function() {
    return function(html) {
        var br = html.indexOf('<br');
        return br === -1 ? html : html.substring(0, br);
    };
})
```

and in your template

```
<span ng-bind-html="event.summary.$t | singleLine"></span>
```